# Batch scripting for date frequencies

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, cmd, scripting

I need your help with some cmd script.

Let me briefly explain my problem.

Now at my company, we have a windows batch file(.bat) that runs daily via scheduler.

This batch file runs a SAS program which triggers two programs based on today's date:

- If today = 2nd Monday of month, then execute program 1.
- If today = 3rd Monday of month, then execute program 2.

So the SAS program which runs daily, executes these two programs based on the date. SAS has pretty cool and easy to use functions(INTNX) for manipulating dates which really helps for people who are new to coding.
Now in an attempt to prevent this SAS program from running daily, I want to see if there is a way to perform this conditional statement within batch scripting to trigger the two programs based on that.

I am new to batch scripting, so after customary research online, I was able to understand few syntax at a very basic level.
This is what I would like to have in my .bat file:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET Today=%B

::Do something to SET Monday2=2nd Monday of current month and Monday3=3rd Monday of current month

IF %Today%==%Monday2% ("D:\Project\Monday2.exe")

IF %Today%==%Monday3% ("D:\Project\Monday3.exe")
```

Could you guys please help me?

It doesn't necessarily have to be in the above format. If there is a better and more efficient way to solve then, I would love to use that.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=. " %%a in ('date /T') do (
        if /I "%%a"=="mo" (
                    if %%b GTR 7 if %%b LEQ 14 set "mo=2dn"
                    ) else (
                    if %%b GTR 14 if %%b LEQ 21 set "mo=3rd"
                    )
        )
```

UNTESTED - only idea (As this monday is 4th....)

Comment: Attention, output of  `date` depends on language  settings. For me, it gives me `29.01.2018`

Comment: did you mean output of 'date /t' or 'echo %date%'

Comment: I get same output for both.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wmic` in conjunction with a `for` loop to get the needed data:

```
@echo off
for /f  %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get WeekInMonth^,DayOfWeek /value ^|find "="') do set /a "%%a"
if %DayOfWeek% neq 1 goto :eof
if %WeekInMonth% == 2 "D:\Project\Monday2.exe"
if %WeekInMonth% == 3 "D:\Project\Monday3.exe"
```

first `if` is to check, if it's a Monday and quit, if it's not. You can omit this line, when you schedule your task to run on Mondays only.

Comment: Stephan,Thanks for your reply. It is very close to what I need. But you see, this wont work for February 2018 because the first week of Feb starts on a Thursday... So the first Monday of the month actually falls in the 2nd week of the month.

Comment: WMIC is not part of all releases of Windows, missing in Home version....

Answer (score 0):

It might be more clear and maintainable to write this in Powershell.

=== domonday.bat

```
powershell -NoProfile -File "./domonday.ps1"
```

=== domonday.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()

$date = Get-Date
Write-Verbose $date.DayOfWeek

if ([Int]($date).DayOfWeek -eq 1) {
    Write-Verbose "day is Monday 1"
    Write-Verbose [String]$date.Day
    if ($date.Day -ge 8 -and $date.Day -le 14) {
        Write-Verbose "Doing second Monday"
        & "D:\Project\Monday2.exe"
    }
    if ($date.Day -ge 15 -and $date.Day -le 21) {
        Write-Verbose "Doing third Monday"
        & "D:\Project\Monday3.exe"
    }
}
```

If you want it without all the Write-Verbose lines:

```
$date = Get-Date
if ([Int]($date).DayOfWeek -eq 1) {
    if ($date.Day -ge 8 -and $date.Day -le 14) { & "D:\Project\Monday2.exe" }
    if ($date.Day -ge 15 -and $date.Day -le 21) { & "D:\Project\Monday3.exe" }
}
```